# external jquery file does not load all content

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I can not find any key word to search on google, so please help me out.

My problem is the external jquery-ui file dose not load all of it content (It's happened sometime when I pressed CTRL + F5) (I have run this project on another PC, and it work correctly)

I am using xampp and I also config virtual host.
I also add all need css file, but it not help.

When I view the source file via chrome (sources tab), the file content is just a haft. I also add all needed css file, but it not help.

You can look at the below image, the source code of jquery-ui.js does not load completely
[image]

Virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tien@test.com 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/samoyed/trunk/src/htdocs"
    ServerName dev.samoyed.vn
    ServerAlias dev.samoyed.vn
    ErrorLog "logs/samoyed.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/samoyed.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Include external jquery file

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

The source code of jquery-ui.min.js I just download it from ui.jquery.com with ver 1.10.4

Sorry because my bad English

Comment: Please post your code (not a picture of the code) here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard edited, I don't do much, just start to include needed file and chrome show me error